# Merkle tree child hashing process

Tags: synchronization, state-trie, merkle-patricia-tries, state-trie-pruning

> Each non leaf node of a Merkle tree is just the hash of the
>   concatenation of it's children.

Does this literally mean stick the 2 hashes together or is there a more intricate process involved?

i.e.

```
Cat(hash1,hash2) => Cat(b5e187f15f1a250e51a7856..,e29ccfc0a7f48e06d19ce02..) =>

Output: b5e187f15f1a250e51a7856..e29ccfc0a7f48e06d19ce02
```

Cannot find description of this process anywhere! Thanks

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself this question too, and by looking at [bitcoin's implementation of merkle trees](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/7466a26cab5d66665991433947964a638f5b957e/src/consensus/merkle.cpp#L83), it seems like the two hashes are first, treated as binary data and second, they're indeed concatenated.

Comment: Wow ok, that seems too simplistic..